# How to JOIN without duplicate rows or JOIN subquery

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have 2 tables, *transactions* and *identifiers*. Each transaction has a user_id, and each user_id can have multiple identifiers e.g.

*transactions*

```
user_id    |    amount     |    timestamp
12              10.00           1234567890
17              5.00            1234567890
12              7.00            1234567890 
3               2.50            1234567890
```

*identifiers*

```
identifier     |     user_id
AEFT67                12
JHDASJK               12
KJSIDJ6               3
LKSDLK                5
HSDJH8                17
IUSDI5                17
```

I'd like to get a result like this:

*result*:

```
user_id      |     identifier       |       amount      |     timestamp
12                  AEFT67                  10.00            1234567890
17                  HSDJH8                   5.00            1234567890
12                  AEFT67                   7.00            1234567890
3                   KJSIDJ6                  2.50            1234567890
```

Both tables have many millions of rows and its important that I don't get duplicates when using a join (otherwise the amounts will be wrong).

I originally tried:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.amount, i.identifier
      FROM transactions AS t 
      LEFT JOIN identifiers AS i ON i.id = (
        SELECT
          i2.id
        FROM identifiers i2 
        WHERE i2.user_id = t.user_id
        LIMIT 1
      )
WHERE t.timestamp BETWEEN 1234567890 AND 1234567890
```

Note - I don't actually mind which identifer I get for a user, but a user could have many. The nested JOIN is very slow (about 40sec) though on large datasets so I tried:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.amount, i1.identifier FROM
    (SELECT *
      FROM transactions as t
    WHERE t.timestamp BETWEEN 1234567890 AND 1234567890) as t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM identifiers GROUP BY user_id) i1
    ON i1.user_id =t1.user_id
```

This actually cut the times down in half, but still very slow.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, in each case I am searching through a lot of data in the *identifiers* table which is slowing it down (millions of rows rather than the 1000 or so needed). I feel that if I was able to use the result of the first query as a parameter in the second it would be much faster i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *
      FROM transactions 
    WHERE t.timestamp BETWEEN 1234567890 AND 1234567890) as t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM identifiers WHERE user_id in (t1.user_id))
```

Is there a better way to get my filtered transactions with a reference to a single (any) identifier?

EDIT: Here's an sql fiddle set up: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecad23/6

EDIT2: For further clarification, I need to maintain a record of every single transaction, so the number of rows returned should be exactly what you'd expect if the where query was only applied to *transactions* table. Users can have multiple transactions so grouping a final result won't work

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to pull a single identifier per user. Do you have any criteria about how the identifier is selected (alphabetical order, string size) or is any one that matches fine?

Comment: @dragmosh no criteria needed for the identifier, any would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the simple query that does what you want is:

```
SELECT 
  t.user_id
  , amount
  , timestamp
  , identifier
FROM 
  transactions AS t 
LEFT JOIN identifiers AS i 
  ON i.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE 
  t.timestamp BETWEEN 1234567890 AND 1234567890  
GROUP BY 
  t.user_id
  , amount
  , timestamp
```

As the query should be fairly easy to execute and optimize by the DBMS I'd guess that you are missing indexes on some column if it isn't fast.

At its core it is a simple join of two tables. One could probably swap `LEFT JOIN` for `JOIN` without any changes in the results if it is ensured, that the consistency of the data is intact, meaning that there always be a user for every transaction.

The duplicates generated by the join are removed again by the GROUP BY. There is no aggregate function on the `identifier` so MySql will simply pick one. This might break if the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` flag is active which would require us to have the `identifier` in an aggregate function. As `identifier` is a `varchar` one cannot simply use one like `MIN` or `MAX`. But if the flag is not set, there is no problem.

**Correction**
Actually I tried and it also seems to be possible to use e.g. MAX on a varchar. I didn't know that.

Comment: Right, that is why the query groups not only by `user_id` but by the triple: `user_id`, `amount` and `timestamp`. So it will keep all rules that have distinct values in any of the three columns.

Comment: sorry deleted my comment before refreshing the page - you're dead right. I tried it on my actual dataset and it didn't work till I fiddled with the GROUP BY and got a distinct value - Thanks! What do you mean by the MAX on varchar btw?

Comment: You would actually be able to replace `identifier` for `MAX(identifier)` in the select list. Don't know how that is calculated then but it appears to work in the fiddle. BTW how is the performance of the query?

Comment: insane, my original adjustment was from 40sec to 23 sec, now I'm at 1.5sec. A quick trip back to the basics. thanks

Comment: `MAX(identifier)` is OK, but `ANY_VALUE(identifier)` is the 'recommended' way.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: These are needed:  on `transactions`: `INDEX(timestamp)`; on `identifiers`: `INDEX(user_id)`

Comment: Thanks @RickJames for that pointer to `ANY_VALUE`. I learned something today.

Comment: Caveat:  `ANY_VALUE()` seems to have been added at MySQL version 5.7.5.  Until then, stick with `MAX()`.

Answer (score 1):

This *may* be faster:

```
SELECT  user_id,
        amount,
        timestamp,
        (
            SELECT identifier FROM identifiers
                    WHERE user_id = t.user_id LIMIT 1
        )   AS identifier
    FROM  transactions AS t
    WHERE  timestamp BETWEEN 1234567890 AND 1234567890
```

Indexes needed:

```
 transactions: INDEX(timestamp)
 identifiers:  INDEX(user_id)
```

A little extra boost would involve using "covering" indexes instead:

```
 transactions: INDEX(timestamp, user_id, amount)
 identifiers:  INDEX(user_id, identifier)
```

Check your `BETWEEN` -- you may be including an extra second at the end.